# Add class to next element in Angular2 Directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive

I have a dropdown menu and I wanna use angular2 directive to handling open/close of this dropdown.
How can I add `open` class to the `latest-notification` div . by knowing that my directive applied to the `button` tag!

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="header-notification" (clickOutside)="showPopupNotification = false">
      <button appDropdown>
        <span [class.has-notification]="hasNotification"></span><icon name="ico_notification"></icon>
      </button>
      <div class="latest-notification">
        <span class="top-pointer"><icon name="arrow-popup"></icon></span>
        <div class="wrap">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let notify of notifications" [class.seen]="notify.seen">
              <a>
                <avatar src="{{notify.userProfileUrl}}" size="35"></avatar>
                <time>{{notify.createAt}}</time>
                <h5>{{notify.name}}</h5>
                <p>{{notify.message}}</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here's my directive:

```
import {Directive, HostBinding, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  private isOpen = false;

  @HostBinding('class.open') get opened() {
    return this.isOpen;
  }

  @HostListener('click') open() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
  constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: @micronyks Sure. How can I achieve that?

Comment: So are you ready?

Comment: @micronyks no wait, let me warm up!!!

Comment: Just kidding buddy as i was working on your problem only. just two mins writing an answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution I found. I don't this is a right way or best way. but at least it's working.

Now by added `toggle` directive to the button directive will be activated and by click on it a class with name of `open` will be added to the next element `latest-notification`. and also when click outside of the button the `open` class will be removed. let me know what your guys thinking .

HTML side:

```
<div class="header-notification">
  <button toggle>
    ...
  </button>
  <div class="latest-notification">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is directive :

```
import {Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Renderer, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[toggle]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  isOpen = false;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {}

  @HostListener('click') open() {
    let nextElement = this.el.nativeElement.nextElementSibling;
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;

    if (this.isOpen === true) {
      this.renderer.setElementClass(nextElement, "open", true);
    } else {
      this.renderer.setElementClass(nextElement, "open", false);
    }
  }

  // close dropdown if clicked outside
  public clickOutside = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
  public onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
    if (!targetElement) {
      return;
    }

    const clickedInside = this.el.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);

    if (!clickedInside) {
      this.clickOutside.emit(event);
      this.isOpen = false;
      let dropdown = this.el.nativeElement.nextElementSibling;
      this.renderer.setElementClass(dropdown,"open", false);
    }
  }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for late respond.

You could use `exportAs` meta property in directive to achieve what you want.

***(I'll show you relevant lines only where you need to make changes)***

---

```
/* #temp is a local template variable */
/* mydir is defined in dropdowndirective as exportAs meta property */

<button #temp=mydir appDropdown>
```

---

```
/* using vc which is defined in dropdown component */
<div class="latest-notification" [class.open]="vc.isOpen" [class.close]="!vc.isOpen">
```

---

```
import {DropdownDirective} from 'path';

export class DropDownComponent{
  @Viewchild('temp') vc:DropdownDirective;  // vc can hold isOpen variable directly defined in Dropdowndirective.
}
```

---

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
  exportAs:'myDir'                          // addded this line
})
```

**Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/AE8n4McCez7ioxiTSExL?p=preview**

Comment: Can you please quickly check and update me whether it works for you or not as I want to go to sleep after 5 min. Just update lines as I have shown you, then you can analysis my solution later.

Comment: Thank you for reply. but I wanna simple solution. in jquery when we have an element by `$element.next()` we can select next element near of the button. I'm locking for something like that in angular2. when I search for it find `Renderer` class, with this class I can select root element it self. it's good but how can I get next element?

Comment: WHy do you get reference of DOM element to do it. Better to use my way. it simple an super easy. at first, i might look tough and hard but it super easy solution. Please don't try to accomplish it jquery way (with angular2) when you can do it with pure angular2.

Comment: I wanted by set a single attr do all of the work and without jquery.

Comment: Why everyone only able using this method only?

Answer (score 0):

Hello i made an improved update to @Sajad answer regarding:

- angular11
- bootstrap 4
- Renderer2
- addClass(), removeClass()

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
      appDropdown
    >
      Manage Recipe
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">To Shop List</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit Recipe</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete Recipe</a>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Directive

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {

  isOpen:boolean = false;

  constructor( private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2 ) { }

  // TOGGLE dropdownMenu
  @HostListener('click') toggleOpen(): void {

    const dropdownMenu: HTMLElement = this.elRef.nativeElement.nextSibling;

    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;

    if( this.isOpen ) {
      this.renderer.addClass(dropdownMenu, 'show');
    }
    else{
      this.renderer.removeClass(dropdownMenu, 'show');
    }
    console.log(this.isOpen);
  }

  // CLOSE dropdown if outside click
  clickOutside = new EventEmitter<Event>();

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
  onClick( event: Event, targetElement: HTMLElement ): void {

    if (!targetElement || this.isOpen === false ) return;

    const dropdownMenu: HTMLElement = this.elRef.nativeElement.nextSibling;
    let clickedInside = this.elRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);

    if (!clickedInside) {
      this.clickOutside.emit(event);
      this.renderer.removeClass(dropdownMenu,'show');
      this.isOpen = false;
    }
  }

}
```